# What characters are allowed as a shortcode tag and how should they be sanitized?

Tags: plugins, filters, shortcode

I am working on a plugin where the user can define shortcode tags himself. What would you suggest to allow in there? My thought is only allow ascii characters.

So how do I sanitize? `strip_tags` and then regex to allow only `a-z, 0-9` or is there a better solution? Does WordPress have filter for that? Could I maybe use the filter WordPress uses for slugs?

thanks for the answers i will just do this, if there must be one ascii char anyway then i just require three.

```
foreach ( $shortcodes as $key => $var ) {

$var = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]/', '', $var ); // strip away everything except a-z,0-9 underscore

if ( strlen($var) < 3 )
    continue; // if less then 3 chars AFTER the strip don't save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use almost every character. Just the character `/` is dangerous. Do not allow it. WordPress is using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg-quote) to escape the shortcode name, but it doesn't include its own regex delimiter `/` when doing that. So the shortcode will not be properly escaped and you get a PHP warning.

Besides that, there are just two basic rules for a shortcode name:

1. It should be at least two characters long.
2. It should contain at least one US-ASCII character (`a-z0-9`).

So this works:

```
foreach ( array ( '.-o', ']b', 'äoß', 'o"o', "o'o", '❤m' ) as $shortcode )
{
    add_shortcode( $shortcode, 't5_crazy_shortcode_handler' );
}

function t5_crazy_shortcode_handler( $attrs = array(), $content = NULL, $shortcode )
{
    return "<pre>\$shortcode: $shortcode\n\n\$attrs\n"
        . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $attrs, TRUE ) )
        . "\n\n\$content"
        . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $content, TRUE ) )
        . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: For clarity, a few more basic rules:  
**3.** You cannot use space in a shortcode tag name  
**4.** Hyphens in tag names should be avoided ([See codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens))
**5.** Parameter names containin dashes don't work in versions of WordPress [prior to July 2015](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9405) although they should be working now.

Answer (score 3):

It seems WordPress has [some issues with shortcodes tags that have hyphens](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens), so you probably want to avoid that. Unsure if this is still an issue with WP 3.3.x.

Most of the 'sanitize' functions in WP's [wp-includes/formatting.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/formatting.php) file (like `sanitize_title`) do work similar to what you might need, but they do allow hyphens. If you only want to return alphanumeric, and not hyphens, you'd probably better off to write a function that takes a string, uses preg_replace to remove spaces and only do alphanumeric. You could replace the spaces with underscores, since it doesn't look like the Shortcode API has issues with those in shortcode tags.